Drawing Equally Spaced Special Shapes Around a Circle in TikZ
I would like to draw eight equal shapes (similar to the one indicated by the blue arrow in the picture below) evenly distributed around a circle. Could someone please guide me on how to achieve this in TikZ?

My Progress so far:
CODE:
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{PoleRed}{HTML}{E60000} % Define a custom green color using hex
\definecolor{PoleGreen}{HTML}{00CC00} % Define a custom green color using hex
\definecolor{PoleBlue}{HTML}{2600E6} % Define a custom green color using hex

% #1 number of teeths
% #2 radius intern
% #3 radius extern
% #4 angle from start to end of the first arc
% #5 angle to decale the second arc from the first
% #6 inner radius to cut off

\newcommand{\ToothedRotorCup}[6]{%
    (0:#2)
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \n using {(\i-1)*(360/#1}] in {1,...,#1}{%
        arc (\n:\n+#4:#2) {[rounded corners=0.5pt] -- (\n+#4+#5:#3)
            arc (\n+#4+#5:\n+360/#1-#5:#3)} --  (\n+360/#1:#2)
    }%
    (0,0) circle[radius=#6] 
}

\newcommand{\AxiallyMagnetizedRotor}{
    \fill[even odd rule, PoleGreen] \ToothedRotorCup{50}{5}{5.3}{2}{1.4}{.1};
    \begin{scope}[rotate=3.6]
        \fill[even odd rule, PoleRed] \ToothedRotorCup{50}{5}{5.3}{2}{1.4}{0.1};
    \end{scope}
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \AxiallyMagnetizedRotor
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

OUTPUT:


OPTIONAL (Challenge):
Are you able to draw the shapes (poleshoes with 6 teeth each) like the one shown below?


UPDATE:
Although it seems like a lot, when you take advantage of the language you can save a lot of work by iterating, the rest is simple style things that I once solved, next you could animate this like in the following link.
UPDATE RESULT:

UPDATE MWE:
\documentclass[tikz,border=6.28pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, patterns.meta,backgrounds}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Serif Font
\definecolor{PoleRed}{HTML}{E60000} % Define a custom green color using hex
\definecolor{PoleGreen}{HTML}{00CC00} % Define a custom green color using hex
\definecolor{PoleBlue}{HTML}{2600E6} % Define a custom green color using hex

% #1 number of teeths
% #2 radius intern
% #3 radius extern
% #4 angle from start to end of the first arc
% #5 angle to decale the second arc from the first
% #6 inner radius to cut off

\newcommand{\ToothedRotorCup}[6]{%
    (0:#2)
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \n using {(\i-1)*(360/#1}] in {1,...,#1}{%
        arc (\n:\n+#4:#2) {[rounded corners=0.5pt] -- (\n+#4+#5:#3)
            arc (\n+#4+#5:\n+360/#1-#5:#3)} --  (\n+360/#1:#2)
    }%
    (0,0) circle[radius=#6] 
}

\newcommand{\AxiallyMagnetizedRotor}{
    \fill[even odd rule, gray!50!blue!50!red] \ToothedRotorCup{50}{5}{5.3}{2}{1.4}{.1};
    \begin{scope}[rotate=3.6]
        \fill[even odd rule, gray!50!blue] \ToothedRotorCup{50}{5}{5.3}{2}{1.4}{0.1};
    \end{scope}

}

%another way to define draw objets
\def\PoleShoeCol[At #1][angle #2][radious #3][color #4][size #5 deg x #6]{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},rotate=#2,transform shape]
        \fill[#4]
        (-#5/2*0.4:#3+0.5+0.25)
            -| (0:#3+#6)
            |- (0+#5/2*0.4:#3+0.5+0.25);
    \end{scope}
}

\def\PoleShoeFeet[At #1][angle #2][radious #3][color #4][arc #5 toes #6]{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},rotate=#2+#5/#6*0.25,transform shape]
        \fill[#4,rounded corners=2.5]
        (#5/2-#5/#6*0.5:#3+1)
        arc (#5/2-#5/#6*0.5:-#5/2:#3+1)
        \foreach \k [evaluate=\k as \j using {\k+1}]in {1,...,#6}{
            -- (-#5/2+#5/#6*\k-#5/#6*1:#3+0.75) 
            -- (-#5/2+#5/#6*\k-#5/#6*0.99:#3+0.5) 
            -- (-#5/2+#5/#6*\k-#5/#6*0.50:#3+0.5) 
            -- (-#5/2+#5/#6*\k-#5/#6*0.49:#3+0.75)
        }
        -- (-#5/2+#5/#6*#6-#5/#6*0.49:#3+1) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]%set the units of coordinates
        \AxiallyMagnetizedRotor
        \foreach \a/\b/\c/\d in {
            0/PoleGreen/A{/}/100,
            45/gray!70!black/B/0,
            90/PoleRed/A/100/-90,
            135/gray!70!black/B{/}/0,
            180/PoleGreen/A{/}/100,
            180+45/gray!70!black/B/0,
            270/red/A/100,
            270+45/gray!70!black/B{/}/0%            
        }{
            \PoleShoeFeet[At 0,0][angle \a][radious 5][color \b][arc 360/50*6 toes 6]
            \node[text=white, scale=2.5,label={[scale=1.2,text=\b!50!white,label distance=-.75em]-90:\d \%}] at (\a:7.2){\c};
        }
        
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \fill[even odd rule,gray!90] (0,0) circle (10) (0,0) circle (10.5);
        \fill[even odd rule,gray!70!black] (45/2+45*0:8.5) \foreach \k in {1,...,7} {-- (45/2+45*\k:8.5)}
        -- cycle (0,0) circle (10) \foreach  \r in {1,...,4}{(45+90*\r:9) circle (0.75)};
        \foreach \m in {0,...,8}{\PoleShoeCol[At 0,0][angle 45*\m][radious 5.2][color gray!70!black][size 50 deg x 3]}
    \end{scope}
    
    \filldraw[even odd rule,gray] (0,0) circle (0.5) (0,0) circle (1);
    
    %Forced radial shade from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/719926/154390
    \foreach \r in {110,110+180,130,130+180}{%forced radial shade
        \foreach \i [evaluate={\s=10}] in {0,1,...,30}{
            \fill [black, fill opacity=1/40]
            (\r+\s-\i:0.5) -- (\r+\s-\i:0.5+0.5)
            arc (\r+\s-\i:\r-\s+\i:0.5+0.5) -- (\r-\s+\i:0.5) arc (\r-\s+\i:\r+\s-\i:0.5);
        }
    }
    
    \foreach \r in {110,110+180,130,130+180, 45,45+180}{%forced radial shade
        \foreach \i [evaluate={\s=10}] in {0,1,...,30}{
            \fill [black, fill opacity=1/40]
            (\r+\s-\i:10) -- (\r+\s-\i:10+0.5)
            arc (\r+\s-\i:\r-\s+\i:10+0.5) -- (\r-\s+\i:10) arc (\r-\s+\i:\r+\s-\i:10);
        }
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Just for fun, an option that uses nesting of drawing codes in definitions with some object properties like color, position and rotation.
You can also change the width of these poleshoes, currently it is 30° of arc, they are defined in size 30 deg x height, which in this case varies from 2 to 1.5 for some cases with elliptical or flattened stators. Sorry for the color change but the red and green in that way left me blind.
RESULT:

MWE:
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, patterns.meta}
\definecolor{PoleRed}{HTML}{E60000} % Define a custom green color using hex
\definecolor{PoleGreen}{HTML}{00CC00} % Define a custom green color using hex
\definecolor{PoleBlue}{HTML}{2600E6} % Define a custom green color using hex

% #1 number of teeths
% #2 radius intern
% #3 radius extern
% #4 angle from start to end of the first arc
% #5 angle to decale the second arc from the first
% #6 inner radius to cut off

\newcommand{\ToothedRotorCup}[6]{%
    (0:#2)
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \n using {(\i-1)*(360/#1}] in {1,...,#1}{%
        arc (\n:\n+#4:#2) {[rounded corners=0.5pt] -- (\n+#4+#5:#3)
            arc (\n+#4+#5:\n+360/#1-#5:#3)} --  (\n+360/#1:#2)
    }%
    (0,0) circle[radius=#6] 
}

\newcommand{\AxiallyMagnetizedRotor}{
    \fill[even odd rule, gray!50!blue!50!red] \ToothedRotorCup{50}{5}{5.3}{2}{1.4}{.1};
    \begin{scope}[rotate=3.6]
        \fill[even odd rule, gray!50!blue] \ToothedRotorCup{50}{5}{5.3}{2}{1.4}{0.1};
    \end{scope}

}

%another way to define draw objets
\def\PoleShoe[At #1][angle #2][radious #3][color #4][size #5 deg x #6]{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},rotate=#2,transform shape]
        \draw[dashed](0:#3+0.3) -- (0:#3+0.3+#6);
        \draw[thick,draw=#4,pattern={Lines[angle=#2+45]},pattern color=#4]
        (#5/2:#3+0.5)
            arc (#5/2:-#5/2:#3+0.5)
            -- (-#5/2:#3+0.5+0.25)
            arc (-#5/2:-#5/2*0.4:#3+0.5+0.25)
            -| (0:#3+#6)
            |- (0+#5/2*0.4:#3+0.5+0.25)
            arc (#5/2*0.4:#5/2:#3+0.5+0.25)
            -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]%set the units of coordinates
        \AxiallyMagnetizedRotor
        \foreach \a/\b/\c in {
            0/red/2,
            45/blue/1.75,
            90/red/1.5,
            135/blue/1.75,
            180/red/2,
            180+45/blue/1.75,
            270/red/2,
            270+45/blue/1.75%           
        }{
            \PoleShoe[At 0,0][angle \a][radious 5][color \b][size 30 deg x \c]
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


hey JLeonV. thanks a lot. that looks also very nice. are you able to draw a poleshoes as I show in the attached picture to my question? best regards

@MarcoMoldenhauer, Yes it sounds more fun, but it will take a while. remember that it is just adding points to the definition of poleshoe. although of course you have to have experience visualizing those points in tikz

Thanks a lot that’s really amazing what you did. Yes later I want animate it also! Have a nice day

Like this?
\def\w{17}
\def\R{5.5}
\def\wPos{90}
%
\pgfmathsetmacro\dw{\w/3}
\pgfmathsetmacro\wStart{\wPos-0.5*\w}
\pgfmathsetmacro\wEnd{\wPos+0.5*\w}
\draw[very thick, blue] ([shift=(\wStart:\R)]0,0)
   arc[start angle=\wStart, end angle=\wEnd, radius=\R]
   -- (\wEnd:6) -- (\wEnd-\dw:6) -- (\wEnd-\dw:7)   
       -- (\wStart+\dw:7) -- (\wStart+\dw:6) --  (\wStart:6) --cycle;   

Or with a foreach-loop:

\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{PoleRed}{HTML}{E60000} % Define a custom green color using hex
\definecolor{PoleGreen}{HTML}{00CC00} % Define a custom green color using hex
\definecolor{PoleBlue}{HTML}{2600E6} % Define a custom green color using hex

% #1 number of teeths
% #2 radius intern
% #3 radius extern
% #4 angle from start to end of the first arc
% #5 angle to decale the second arc from the first
% #6 inner radius to cut off

\newcommand{\ToothedRotorCup}[6]{%
    (0:#2)
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \n using {(\i-1)*(360/#1}] in {1,...,#1}{%
        arc (\n:\n+#4:#2) {[rounded corners=0.5pt] -- (\n+#4+#5:#3)
            arc (\n+#4+#5:\n+360/#1-#5:#3)} --  (\n+360/#1:#2)
    }%
    (0,0) circle[radius=#6] 
}

\newcommand{\AxiallyMagnetizedRotor}{
    \fill[even odd rule, PoleGreen] \ToothedRotorCup{50}{5}{5.3}{2}{1.4}{.1};
    \begin{scope}[rotate=3.6]
        \fill[even odd rule, PoleRed] \ToothedRotorCup{50}{5}{5.3}{2}{1.4}{0.1};
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\AxiallyMagnetizedRotor

\def\w{17}
\def\R{5.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\dw{\w/3}
%
\foreach \wPos in {0,45,...,315}{%%
%\def\wPos{90}% Test
\pgfmathsetmacro\wStart{\wPos-0.5*\w}
\pgfmathsetmacro\wEnd{\wPos+0.5*\w}
\draw[very thick, blue] ([shift=(\wStart:\R)]0,0)
   arc[start angle=\wStart, end angle=\wEnd, radius=\R]
   -- (\wEnd:6) -- (\wEnd-\dw:6) -- (\wEnd-\dw:7)   
       -- (\wStart+\dw:7) -- (\wStart+\dw:6) --  (\wStart:6) --cycle;   

\draw[densely dashed] (\wStart+1.5*\dw:5.35) -- (\wStart+1.5*\dw:7.35); 
}%%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


thanks a lot cis!!

Note: I accidentally had \w, \dw and \R inside the loop. Of course we don't need that. Corrected.

hey cis are you able to draw the shape like i am showing in my picture attached above in my question? That would be the best since this is how my stepper motor exactly looks like. thanks in advance.

You mean the new picture.... You should open a new thread with a new approach. Changing a thread with a new or different task after the fact is not so good.
